# Finding marginal mass functions

Tags: probability

> The joint probability mass function of the lifetimes $X$ and $Y$ of
> two connected components in a machine can by modeled by $p(x,y) =
>  \dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-2}}{x!(y-x)!}$ for $x=0,1,...$ and $y=x,x+1,...$.
> What is the joint probability mass function of $X$ and $Y-X$? What are
> the marginal distributions of $X$, $Y-X$ and $Y$?

### Attempt

First, we want to find

$$ P(X=x, Y-X=n) = P(X=x, Y=x+n) = \boxed{\frac{e^{-2}}{x!n!}}$$

For the marginal,

$$ p_X(x) = P(X=x) = \sum_{y=x}^{\infty} \dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-2}}{x!(y-x)!} = \frac{e^{-2}}{x!} \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{y!} = \frac{e^{-2}e }{x!} = \boxed{ \frac{e^{-1}}{x!}} $$

$$ p_Y(y) = \sum_{x=0}^{\infty} \dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-2}}{x!(y-x)!} = \sum_{x \geq 0} \frac{e^{-2}}{y!} {y \choose x}= \frac{e^{-2}}{y!} \sum_{x \geq 0} {y \choose x} = ...$$

Isn't the above $2^{\infty} $?

finally,

$$ p_{Y-X}(n) = \sum_{x = 0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2}}{x!n!}= \boxed{ \frac{e^{-2}e}{n!} } $$

am I on the right track?

Comment: You missed $Y \geq X.$